# To infinitive or not infinitive?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, infinitives, conjunction-reduction

In the following sentence:

"My job was to ride all of the horses and then to feed all of those horses."

Do I need a "to" before the word "feed?"

Comment: Your choice....

Comment: Is there a formal explanation for this?

Comment: It depends on how you want it parsed.  One prepositional phrase with the conjunction inside the phrase, or two separate phrases joined by the conjunction.

Comment: [Conjuncton Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22conjunction+reduction%22), which is the rule that deletes the second _to_, is optional; i.e, you're not required to apply it. That's the formal explanation for why both constructions are grammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sometimes it helps the meter: "To be or not be..." wouldn't work as well in Hamlet.

Comment: Yes, I think a lot of these optional marker deletion rules are just to give the speaker the power to manage the rhythmic flow properly. Sometimes you want an extra syllable or two to add weight where it's needed.

Comment: Calling it an "optional marker deletion rule" seems to me to be a phony way to say that there may be multiple ways to phrase something, and in a few cases there are "mechanical" strategies for transforming from one phrasing to another.

Comment: _My job was to ride all the horses and feed them._

Answer (score 1):

First simplify it to the essential part:

> to ride and to feed

and ignore the noise.

The "and" can link words together in either of two ways:

- "to ride" and "to feed" → "to ride and to feed"
- "ride" and "feed" → "to ride and feed"

So either way is fine.

Split-no-infinitive pedants would object to the second form though, as the "to
feed" has "ride and" inserted between the "to" and the "feed".
Feel free to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you do need "to", but it does no harm - your meaning is totally clear. You can also change it to " then (to) feed them all."